# Load more posts in the same page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, posts

I have this code

```
    <ul>
        <?php query_posts('showposts=3&cat=3,4,5'); ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="Ver projeto">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail(full);?></a>
          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="ico-<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->slug; ?>">
          <?php
$category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->name; ?>
          </a>
          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="Ver projeto"><p class="fizemos">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </p>
          <p class="empresa">
            <?php the_subtitle(); ?>
          </p>
          </a> </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </ul>
```

And I want the next page of posts opens in the same page (home page in this case).
I tryed the the PBD Ajax Load Posts plugin and don't worked.
You know a way to do this? Can be just jQuery to hide the posts and when I click "Load more entries..." they give me the content that are hidden. (3 per time)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have a jQuery... I tryed the PBD plugin but don't worked. :/

Comment: check the settings for the plugin you can probably set it there how the content should be loaded and what not

Comment: that plugin just works to default theme (posts page) and don't work in this case. (need something like /page/2/... /page/3/) and my homepage don't have this.

Comment: @Thiago nah the problem is probably the selectors, and if you add to the top of your code, `<?php query_posts('showposts=3&cat=3,4,5&paged='.((get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)); ?>`
you pagination should start working too

Comment: added this and now i get "pbd_alp is not defined" - know why? tks!

Comment: in the tutorial he says: "Finally, we send over an array of the data. If you view the HTML source of your webpage later, you’ll see something like this right before your JavaScript file is loaded:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var pbd_alp = {
 startPage: "1",
 maxPages: "6",
 nextLink: "http://www.problogdesign.com/demo/ajax-load-posts/page/2/"
};
/* ]]> */
</script>" but i dont have this added

Answer (score 0):

Pagination won't work correctly, unless you use query_posts() in a page template and you set the 'paged' query var appropriately: [how to set 'paged'](http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html)

more info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Pagination)